# Android: Mistakenly cleaned the project and lost R file

Tags: android-resources

I am new in android development. The R file was not detecting two layouts for which I cleaned the project and lost R file. It is no more present in gen folder and all of the classes are showing error. Build option is checked i.e, I can't build project. I can't afford recreating the project at this stage. So any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Manifest was containing errors. The Manifest file was using layout names in the android:label property of activities which Manifest wasn't detecting as R file was deleted. I changed label to app_name and On fixing Manifest errors, the R file regenerated. It could be helpful in case someone else encountered the same problem.